# Trying to change the user input for selecting value from chomp game

Tags: python, python-3.x

Working on chomp game as part of a programming course in Python where the user should be asked to choose to get rid of a value that has been printed and positioned in an row, col format like this:
[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ozx7h.jpg)

So basically when the user chooses 55 in the 2d array, all block of values equal to or greater than 55 are automatically vanished from the array.

However as of now the user is required to enter row and column before a set of data is deleted, anyone know how to implement this change aforementioned.

Here's my code below:

```
def create_chocolate_bar(rows, columns):#creates chocolate bar
    each_columns_worth = 1
    chocolate_bar = []#creates a matrix for chocolate_bar
    if rows in range(1,10) and columns in range(1, 10):#checks that integer isn't less than 1 or larger than 9.
        for r in range(1, rows+1):#determines which row will be assigned 
            columns_worth = []
            for k in range(1,columns+1):#specifies value to specific column
                each_columns_worth = r*10+k #calculates the value for the chosen column
                columns_worth.append(each_columns_worth)
            chocolate_bar.append(columns_worth)
        chocolate_bar[0][0] = "P "
        return chocolate_bar
    else:
        return False

def print_chocolate_bar(a):#printar chocolate baren
    for current_row in range(0, len(a)):#determines which element within the matrix will be assigned
        for current_col in range(0, len(a[current_row])):#determines which list within the matrix will be printed respectively
            print(a[current_row][current_col], end=" ")#prints what was given in the previous row 
        print("\n")#prints new row

def chomp(matrix, row, col):#function that deletes what the user has chosen to delete
    for x in range(row, len(matrix)):#determines the row we're working with 
        del matrix[x][col:]#deletes from row x and the column chosen by the user as well as everything behind it in the current list
    print_chocolate_bar(matrix)

def check_winner(matrix):
    if len(matrix) == 1 and len(matrix[0]) == 1:
        return True
    elif matrix == [["blahonga"]]:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def main(): #main function
    rows = int(input("How many rows do you want your chocolate bar to be?")) #asks user input for rows
    columns = int(input("How many columns do you want you cholate bar to be?"))#aks user input for columns
    if create_chocolate_bar(rows,columns) != False:
        print_chocolate_bar(create_chocolate_bar(rows, columns))#calls create_chocolate_bar function and prints the function
        remove = input("Do you want to remove a part of the chocolate bar? y/n")#asks the user if something should be deleted 
        if (remove == "Y" or remove == "y"):#will call chomp and it will ask from which row and which columns you want to delete and send them to the chomp function
            row = int(input("From which row do you want to start removing?"))
            col = int(input("From which column do you want to start removing?"))
            chomp(create_chocolate_bar(rows, columns), row, col)
        else:
            print("Goodbye!")#if you don't want to chomp the code will automatically execute to exit the game 
    else:
        print("That's not a valid number! Please try again.")
    main()


main()#runs main function
```

Comment: I don't fully understand the game rules, but you keep calling `create_chocolate_bar()` but you probably just want to call this once and store the result: `chocolate_bar = create_chocolate_bar(rows, columns)`. Then use `chocolate_bar` in subsequent functions.

Comment: I was thinking that in the main function when the user is asked for two inputs (row and col), how I instead can make it into a single input where if the user enters a value  that has been printed in the matrix such that the any number equal or greater than the value input should be deleted from the chocolate bar.